# What's that word for an artist who--

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been wracking my brain trying to remember a word for a try-hard, pleb artist! It starts with a "d", if I remember correctly, and I'm sorry if the details aren't enough and such. You know, even the definition of this supposed "d" word I can't remember, I'm also quite hazy with. Though I think the general gist of it is mildly derogatory but in a "stating the facts" kinda way. An artist that can't be great or masquerading to be great or something... Starts with a "d" I think... Oof! Any suggestions? Answers?

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is **[dilettante](https://www.google.com/search?q=diatant&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS734US735&oq=diatant&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3222j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=dilettante).**

> a person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge.

Comment: That's it! Wonderful! Thank you! I was so upset I forgot it, my goodness. Thanks again!

Comment: @HarryMckenzie You're welcome.  If it answered your question, you can feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it.  :)

Comment: No, it would be better if people checked to see if the question has been asked already.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fair enough, I suppose.  Maybe try closing these questions before I answer them if it bothers you so much as to warrant a downvote. Or maybe it's helpful to the OP that I answered the question.

Comment: It's considered to be the responsibility of anyone desiring to maintain / improve standards here to avoid duplication as being unprofessional and damaging to the status (and value) of the site. Perhaps you could help? This isn't in the first instance a site for providing answers to all questions that may appear. If it were, there would _be_ no close-voting. // Now you've helped the OP here, you could delete your answer and show you really have everybody's interests at heart.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree, I just don't have the rep to close-vote yet.  From my perspective, answering a question with a clear zero-sum answer is better than writing a comment saying "hey have you tried googling to see if this site has already answered the question."  I agree, though, that the site is best served by maintaining clear individual answers to questions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth to take your comment literally though, no, I don't agree that deleting my answer would benefit the site.  Closing the question would.  The answer has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Closing questions is a process requiring the votes of 5 contributors with rep over 3K, or the intervention of a moderator. However, it is _the responsibility of anyone who wishes to post an answer_ to determine if a question is closable as a duplicate or as answerable in a general reference.

Comment: @Cascabel point taken and I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: I assume that 'I'll keep that in mind' is sincere and that you'll retract the answer and close-vote now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what is the level of required diligence in checking to see if something is a duplicate, as an answerer?  I thought this seemed to be a novel question, and I'm not in the habit of specifically scanning for duplicates on stack exchange.  The same is true of the infinitive question I answered.  I'm being sincere when I ask to what extent it's my responsibility to check if something is a dupe before I answer **any** question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and to your requests, I don't see the point of deleting an answer on a question that should be closed.  The question should just be closed.  And I'm 20 reputation points short of being able to close vote, or even learning how that works.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is there a way to get another user's input on that question, besides posting it as a question on meta?  Because I think it's a valid question.  Sometimes a question seems unique enough, or is *phrased* uniquely enough, that it's difficult to google for duplicates.  For instance, someone looking for a word starting with the letter 'D'.  That seems like a pretty specific request.  And there are definitely cases where the question is even more difficult to search for duplicates on.  I just don't know to what extent we're obligated to research for duplication before answering.

Comment: Answer, look up 'dilettante' in an in-house search, then delete your answer and close-vote.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth again, deleting answers from bad questions doesn't help the site unless the answers are *wrong*, and again, I cannot vote to close.  I will try to check for duplicate answers in the future.  Thanks for your candor.

Comment: Yes it does. Where the answers have been given before, it helps to keep the site tidy and unbloated.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth infinitive answer deleted.